# how to write a grafana simple json to table query from a json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, grafana

how to convert that data(json) to pandas Dataframe so that it can populate the "keys" as columns and "values" as rows in a grafana simple json to table dynamically. actually, it's not in a perfect array format how do I manipulate it to work as data frame? help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data = {"name":"john","class":"fifth"}
       {"name":"emma","class":"sixth"}
```

I want to populate keys as columns and rows as values dynamically no matter how many json's we have.

Comment: The data variable seems not to be valid json or python dict.
Did you mean 
```data = [ {"name": "john", "class": "fifth"}, 
{"name": "emma","class":"sixth"}]```

Comment: @sarbot there is no comma after first JSON object. how do make these multiple json's into one json and make a dataframe out of it as keys as columns and values as rows?

Comment: I think there should be.. I'm not an json expert but it's no valid python (and i think also no valid json). Where do you got the json data from? Do you want to load many json objects or files? Than I would add a code example to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` method. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

An example could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"name":"john","class":"fifth"},
       {"name":"emma","class":"sixth"}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Result:

```
   class  name
0  fifth  john
1  sixth  emma
```

In this case data is already a list of dictionaries (I assume this is what you mean in your question). If you have the data in JSON-Strings/Files you can use `json.loads(data_string)` / `json.load(data_file)` from the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

### Update

For the grafana table data structure like this:

```
data = [
  {
    "columns":[
      {"text":"Time","type":"time"},
      {"text":"Country","type":"string"},
      {"text":"Number","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      [1234567,"SE",123],
      [1234567,"DE",231],
      [1234567,"US",321]
    ],
    "type":"table"
  }
]
```

A pandas dataframe can be created:

```
keys = [d['text'] for d in data[0]['columns']]
pd.DataFrame(data=data[0]['rows'], columns=keys)
```

For a result like:

```
   Time     Country  Number
0  1234567  "SE"     123
1  1234567  "DE"     231
2  1234567  "US"     312
```

Comment: in your code the json is ina structure but in , my case i have multiple json objetcts. I dont have comma after each json object

Comment: I've never used grafana, do you read the data as string or from file. Are the objects seperated by linebreaks? than you could simply use `data.split('\n')` or `readlines()` for files...

Comment: the grafana format should be like this                                                                                   
https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource check for  json to table format in that link

Comment: ok, so you have way more data than given in your question.. I think I got your "problem" now ;)

Comment: updated the answer again, if this is not what you want, you need to give me a full example of the input data and the final dataframe (table) you want to create.